# Rubyで、なぜかnilになる

Tags: ruby

以下のコードは、ABC310-B(https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc310/tasks/abc310_b)を解こうとして書いたコードです。

```
class Product
    attr_accessor :price, :fncs
    def initialize(price, fncs)
        @price, @fnc=price, fncs
    end
end
n,m=gets.chomp.split(" ").map(&:to_i)
ps=[]
n.times do |i|
    t=gets.chomp.split(" ").map(&:to_i)
    pr=t.delete_at(0)
    t.delete_at(0)
    ps.push(Product.new(pr,t))
end
#p ps
(1..n).to_a.permutation(2).to_a.each do |perm|
#    p perm
    i=perm[0]-1
    j=perm[1]-1
#puts "#{i} #{j}"
"puts "#{ps[i]} #{ps[j]}"
    if ps[i].price<ps[j].price
        next
    end
    flag=true
    ps[i].fncs.each do |f|
        if !ps[j].fncs.include?(f)
            flag=false
            break
        end
    end
    if flag==false
        next
    end
    if ps[i].price>ps[j].price
        puts "Yes"
        exit
    end
    ps[j].fncs.each.do |f|
        if !ps[i].fncs.include?(f)
        puts "Yes"
        exit
    end
end
puts "No"
```

価格price(整数)と機能fncs(配列)をメンバに持つクラスの配列psを作り、その中で、

1. ps[i].price>=ps[j].price
2. ps[i].fncsの全ての要素はps[j].fncsにも含まれる
3. 「ps[i].price>ps[j].price」または「ps[j].fncsにはps[i].fncsに含まれない要素がある」

の全てが成り立つ(1⋀2⋀3)かどうかを調べようとしています。

ここで、26行目の

```
ps[i].fncs.each do |f|
```

のところで、

```
Main.rb:26:in `block in <main>': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

    ps[i].fncs.each do |f|
```

というエラーが出て止まってしまいます。
n個の配列の生成とn個から2個選んで並べる配列の生成まではできているのに、なぜ`ps[i].fncs`が`nil`になるのか分かりません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

クラス `Product` のイニシャライザーで `@fncs` を `@fnc` に typo しています。

```
class Product
    attr_accessor :price, :fncs
    def initialize(price, fncs)
        @price, @fnc=price, fncs
        #       ^^^^
    end
end
```

`ps[i].fncs` が `nil` になっているというエラーなので、疑うべきは `fncs` に値を書き込んでいるところです。このプログラムで `fncs` に代入している箇所としてまず `Product.new` しているあたりを調べて、そこは大丈夫そうだったので次にイニシャライザーを見に行ったら打ち間違いに気付きました。